# Declarative Security--what's this?

Tags: java

How can I define the term "Declarative Security" in context of web programming? Is it same like defining "Declarative Programming"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is the opposite of "Programmatic Security." You can define the security attributes of a "bean" or component by using XML in the appropriate place, or annotations in the Java class.

The JavaEE 6 tutorial has a section called [Using Deployment Descriptors for Declarative Security.](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbxe.html#bnbxf)

> In Java EE, the component containers
>   are responsible for providing
>   application security. A container
>   provides two types of security:
>   declarative and programmatic.